# Run-time parameters in gcc (inverse va_args/varargs)

Tags: c, function, gcc, argument-passing, variadic-functions

I'm trying to make some improvements to a interpreter for microcontrollers that I'm working on. For executing built-in functions I currently have something like this (albeit a bit faster):

```
function executeBuiltin(functionName, functionArgs) {
  if (functionName=="foo") foo(getIntFromArg(functionArgs[0]));
  if (functionName=="bar") bar(getIntFromArg(functionArgs[0]),getBoolFromArg(functionArgs[1]),getFloatFromArg(functionArgs[2]));
  if (functionName=="baz") baz();
  ...
}
```

But it is for an embedded device (ARM) with very limited resources, and I need to cut down on the code size drastically. What I'd like to do is to have a general-purpose function for calling other functions with **different arguments** - something like this:

```
function executeBuiltin(functionName, functionArgs) {
  functionData = fast_lookup(functionName);
  call_with_args(functionData.functionPointer, functionData.functionArgumentTypes, functionArgs);
}
```

So I want to be able to call a standard C function and pass it whatever arguments it needs (which could all be of different types). For this, I need a `call_with_args` function.

I want to avoid re-writing every function to take argc+argv. Ideally each function that was called would be an entirely standard C function.

There's a [discussion about this here](http://c-faq.com/varargs/invvarargs.19930307.html) - but has anything changed since 1993 when that post was written? Especially as I'm running on ARM where arguments are in registers rather than on the stack. Even if it's not in standard C, is there anything GCC specific that can be done?

---

**UPDATE:** It seems that despite behaviour being 'undefined' according to the spec, it looks like because of the way C calls work, you can pass more arguments to a function than it is expecting and everything will be fine, so you can unpack all the arguments into an array of uint32s, and can then just pass each uint32 to the function.

That makes writing 'nice' code for calls much easier, and it appears to work pretty well (on 32 bit platforms). The only problem seems to be when passing 64 bit numbers and compiling for 64bit x86 as it seems to do something particularly strange in that case.

Comment: [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) might help. If you have to reduce memory footprint, it might be too large to include, but the source code should give you some pointers.

Comment: yep! I've found the same as per your update, using a vararg function pointer. In fact in the [link I have already referred on arm arch](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf) it's stated that "A variadic function is always marshaled as for the base standard". But before posting I'd like to investigate a little more. You've got it before me - good! xf86_64 is another beast again, since it uses (on linux) cdecl convention - some operands (FP values for sure) are passed on registers. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl.

Comment: Thanks! So that's a bit of a nightmare - if floating point and integers are handled differently it's particularly painful. I guess I may have to make a signature-based caller for x86 (where code size doesn't matter too much) and then I can get away with something far simpler on ARM.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to do at compile time with macros?
Something along the lines of:
https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2014-March/msg00730.html

If runtime was required, perhaps __buildin_apply_args() could be leveraged.

Comment: __builtin_apply looks really interesting. I'm yet to find an example that does quite what I want, but it seems very promising - I'll have to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

from [this document](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf), section 5.5, *Parameter Passing*, it seems like parameters are passed both in registers and in stack, as with most of today platforms.

With "non standard C" I am thinking to pack the parameters and call the function following the documentation with some `asm()`. However you need a minimal information about the signature of the function being called anyway (I mean, how many bits for each argument to be passed).

From this point of view I would prefer to prepare an array of function names, an array of function pointers and an array of enumerated function signatures (in the number of bits of each argument... you don't need to differentiate void* from char* for example) and a switch/case on the signatures, and a switch/case on the last one. So I have reported two answers here.

Comment: I have roughly 400 functions and I expect that to grow. I'll have to look at how many unique signatures there are, but my feeling is that it's probably quite a lot, and will mean that having a switch of the signatures will be quite far from ideal.

As far as pushing the correct parameters with assembler - yes that could be done, however the question was really whether there was a va_args equivalent or whether nothing has changed from 1993 (it seems it hasn't).

It looks a lot like nwellnhof's suggestion of libffi is the closest to a neat solution at the moment.

Comment: Just to add, I checked up and there are 400 functions with 25 unique signatures if I classify each argument into 32 of 64 bit and over 80 if I don't. IMO it's enough that a more flexible approach would be prefereable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a very simple serialization to pass arbitrary arguments. Create an array and memcpy sizeof(arg) bytes into it for each passed argument.

Or you can create structs for function arguments.

Every function takes a char* or a void*. Then you pass either a pointer to a struct with that functions parameters, or you define a set of macros or functions to encode and decode arbitrary data from an array and pass the pointer to that array.

Comment: I'm not sure this solves the problem of calling an existing library function, such as `sin`?

Comment: @GordonWilliams you couldn't call those using varargs either. So you'd need a proxy function to decode it and then call sin.