# C late binding with unknown arguments

Tags: c, dynamic, binding, function-pointers

I am presently in a case where I need to call a  lot of function pointers that has been extracted at runtime.  The problem is that the arguments are unknown at compilation time.

But, at runtime I receive datas that allows me to know the arguments of the function and I can even store the arguments in a char* array.  The problem is that I don't have a function pointer model to cast it into.

In high level language, I know there is function like "InvokeMethode(String name,Byte[] args)" that interpret the bytes array like arguments.  Since reflection does not exist in C, I have no hope to see this with a function pointer.

One solution that I have in mind (and it's really bad), is to create a model of function pointer at compilation time that will cast in a "hardcoded way" the ptr to the right type to use like this:

```
void callFunc64Bits(void* funcPtr,long long args);
void callFuncVoid(void* funcPtr);
```

The problem is that I will have to create like 100 function like this that will cast the pointer correctly.

Is there a way to do it more efficiently?

Thank you very much!

Comment: So make all of the functions to take as a parameter `void*`, and be happy..

Comment: Well, i'm not the one who wrote the functions that I need to load in a dynamic way

Comment: Then, I afraid there is now way of doing it, unless you pass the information about the argument types along and then making a wrapper to call the functions.

Comment: you need to create an API or a protocol (standard or whatever). that describe function parameters. and build tools that parses arguments and passes them to functions (same way that web services do eg: `WSDL`), an other working example is the way that `printf` parses its arguments)

Comment: I already have the first part (description of function parameter).  I don't understand how I can do the second part.  How can I pass my datas to the function if I have no cast for them written at compilation.  Thank you!
Edit:  Thank your for the printf exemple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hard problem without, unfortunately, good or easy answers.

See this former SO question: [Run-time parameters in gcc (inverse va_args/varargs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169879/run-time-parameters-in-gcc-inverse-va-args-varargs)

See this C FAQ question: http://c-faq.com/varargs/invvarargs.html

See this collection of "wacky ideas" by the C FAQ list maintainer: http://c-faq.com/varargs/wacky.html

---

Addendum: see this former SO question: [How to call functions by their pointers passing multiple arguments in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206865/how-to-call-functions-by-their-pointers-passing-multiple-arguments-in-c)

...which mentions "libffi": http://sourceware.org/libffi/

Comment: libfii seems quite a good problem solver in my case.  I'm waiting for more answer but it may be the final solution. Thank you!!