# How do I call a function whose declaration is unknown at compiletime

Tags: c, ffi

this is bascially the problem.

```
void call_function(void* func, const char* funcdecl, void* arguments) {

  // how do I do this?

  // some pseudo code
  for(i = 0; i < numargs; ++i) {
    if(funcdecl.args[i].type == TYPE_DOUBLE) {
      push funcdecl.args[i].doubleValue
    }
    ...
  }
  call func
  reslut.type = funcdecl.result_type;
  if(funcdecl.result_type == TYPE) {
    result.value = read_doulbe_from_stack();
  }
}


// nothing from here on is known before call_function.

double foobar(int a, int b, int c) {
  return a * 0.1 + b * 0.3 + c * 0.2;
}

typedef struct MyArgumentsStruct {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
} MyArgumentsStruct;

int main() {
  MyArgumentsStruct arguments;
  call_function( (void*)(foobar), "double foobar(int a, int b, int c);", &arguments);
}
```

so basically I cant cast the `void*` to a function type, because I don't know it.

I have looked up what gcc does when compiling to asm. And when I understand it correctly, it generates a lot of `push` instructions to push all function arguments on the stack, and then it uses `call` to go to a function. The function then knows how to get the arguments from the stack and pushes the result back.

So my question is, how do I push arguments from manually to the stack?
How would I read the return value from the stack?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C late binding with unknown arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885868/c-late-binding-with-unknown-arguments)

Comment: You need assembly code for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking to solve the problem, then pick a library like `libffi` (see the question linked by @SteveSummit).

If you want to learn how it is done, you will need to have a grasp on assembly. Start by simplifying the problem by picking a single architecture, single calling convention, no arguments, leave the parsing of the C function declaration for later, etc. As soon as you manage to make the simplest function call successfully, you can proceed to study the rest of details -- there are many!