# How to create an args list for vscanf / vprinf directly?

Tags: c

I know how to call vprintf, etc from an implementation of printf, correspondingly.

But what if I want to create an argument list dynamically in code, especially for `vsscanf`, where I know they are all pointers?

Is there some reasonably portable way that I can convert my dynamically allocated and filled array of pointers (actually a std::vector) into a va_list?

This is all so that I can add a %n argument to the end and detect how much input was actually consumed, in order to provide an answer to ftell in my own FILE-like wrapper.

Other than doing something hairy with a pipe; or writing my own implementation; or splitting the string and doing one argument at a time; I don't see how else I can detect the input stream usage, especially for sscanf. So other ideas to that end might be interesting.

Comment: You really **can't** in pure C  much less in any "reasonably portable way".  Just look for the GCC implementation of `__builtin_va_start()` for an example of what you'd need to do.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I think OP might actually be using C++ as he is using vectors

Comment: My published API is C, and of course varargs is C, but I don't mind resorting to a little C++ when it helps.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand what [your *actual* problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here is, but I would be rather interested to hear it. You're talking about "providing an answer to ftell" in your "own FILE-like wrapper". That sounds like you're implementing a C library...?!?

Comment: The [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) project supports many ABIs, maybe it supports yours.

Comment: You might find some hints at [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885868/c-late-binding-with-unknown-arguments).

Comment: @DevSolar Yes, something like that... a level of clib interception, but where possible falling back on the supplied functionality. So I have access to the standard library, and use it where I can.

Comment: @GemTaylor: If you are interested in discussing your approach with someone who's (in the process of) implementing a C library that is *designed* to make tinkering / adjusting it as easy as possible (and who'd be interested if my approach would actually work for you), find me at [pdclib.rootdirectory.de](http://pdclib.rootdirectory.de)...

Answer (score 1):

Argument lists, be they fixed or variable sized, are static compile-time entities. So in runtime you can read them, but not create. Use conventional pointers instead.

The sole purpose of `va_list` is an iteration through arguments because nothing else provides durable access to them. So treat it as a roundabout for a specific feature of a language (a possibility to pass more arguments than specified in a prototype), not intended to be used anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

X-Y answer: In the end I used fopencookie and vfscanf on that, so I didn't have to process the arguments nor process the format string.