# C execute function with list of arguments

Tags: c, arguments, apply, variadic-functions

I need to evaluate function with list of arguments from array of arguments as in this example:

```
int compute(...) {
    int n;
    va_list params;
    va_start(params, n);
    // some custom computation with no "va" output
    va_end(params);
}
```

And some array of int (which is dynamic array, don't rely on fixed size):

```
int arr[10] = {0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
```

And I need to call `compute` like JS function `compute.apply(this, arr)`

I'm implementing some library with C that's why I need it.

In C++ this is [std::apply](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) but I want the same in C.

Thanks

Comment: So ? What is your question exactly ?

Comment: Hm. Variadic functions are probably not what you need here. If you want to operate on an array of `n` elements, write a function that takes that array and its length as parameters: `int compute(const int *arr, size_t n) `.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean I need something like `std::apply` from C++ in C

Comment: @MOehm I don't like this way. I just demonstrated that I accept flexible number of args in my function I want to invoke.

Comment: It's not whether you like it or not, it's whether C can do it or not. Also, you didn't demonstrate anything. How do you want to call your proposed `compute` function with the given array?

Comment: @MOehm well it's because I use a lot thing and I have huge and irrelevant to my problem code... But speaking shortly it's just wrapper around `pthread.h` in order to implement callbacks and fire them by the timer... I googled a lot of stuff and didn't find the best solution. So I need to invoke function with argument list because all those arguments are coming from handlers to this low-level function.

Comment: @MOehm > it's whether C can do it or not.
That's what I'm asking... Otherwise switching to C++ is the best way to solve my problem. I don't want it because I like C libraries I'm using and I use functional programming instead of classes...

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are asking. Do you require a function that operates on (arrays of) different types? Do you want the elements to be of different types within a single array? C++'s `std::apply` and JS's `func.apply()` reduce the array to a single element. Such things can be done in C, but not as flexibly as in these languages. Perhaps you can edit the question and expand on your example and add a typical use case.

Comment: @MOehm it's not easy to explain the whole idea but I have to mix different types as well as `tuple` in C++. Can it be done just exactly like in C++?

Comment: @featureoffuture " I just demonstrated that I accept flexible number of args in my function" You didn't demonstrate anything. Explain your problem clearly first and we'll be (perhaps) able to help you. You're talking about variadoc functions but only mention a use case where you pass one array and its size as parameters

Comment: If your arrays are of a homogenous type, you can use the raw pointer + byte size approach of `qsort` [like this](https://ideone.com/34N5L9). If your arrays can be heterogenous, you can create a variant type as a tagged union [like this](https://ideone.com/5h3SiQ). Note how both approaches still must manage their memory explicitly. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I suspect, though I am not sure, that your question is the same as: [*C late binding with unknown arguments*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885868/c-late-binding-with-unknown-arguments).  (And the answer you want is probably [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/), although it can be a bit tricky to use.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In C++ this is [std::apply](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) but I want the same in C.

Since you *want the same in C*, you'll surely accept that you have to fulfill the same requirements, in particular, as a *tuple* *supports `std::get` and `std::tuple_size`*, their C equivalents. Now, as long as the arguments from the array are accessed in order from first to last, `std::get` can be implemented with `va_…()`, but just as the *stdarg* variable argument lists need some means of determining the amount of arguments (like a format string or an argument count), `std::tuple_size` cannot be implemented without such a means. You won't do without passing this information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I decided just move project to C++ since I can combine C and C++ features. I also need to run a function in a separate thread for example... C++ is the best with this. But it looks like you're the only person who got my question. Idk why nobody else wants the same feature in C...

Comment: I can well imagine people wanting the same feature in C, it's just that C as it is doesn't provide a means of implicitly passing the needed size information, and there are high barriers for a language standard change.