# Mac native function (ObjC / LibC) to call function with arguments

Tags: c, objective-c, vba, macos, objective-c-runtime

I maintain a 'modern' VBA library on github [stdVBA](https://github.com/sancarn/stdVBA). The library provides a high level wrapper on top of many low level functions in Windows OS. Mac compatibility is desired and the main obstruction is entry to the ObjC API.

We can get classes using `objc_lookUpClass` and get pointers to methods with `class_getMethodImplementation`:

```vb
Private Declare Function objc_lookUpClass Lib "/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib" (ByVal sClassName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare Function class_getMethodImplementation Lib "/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib" (ByVal klass as LongPtr, ByVal sClassName As String) As LongPtr

Sub main()
  Dim lKlass as LongPtr: lKlass = objc_lookUpClass("NSRegularExpression")
  Dim lMethod as LongPtr: lMethod = class_getMethodImplementation(lKlass, "regularExpressionWithPattern")
  Dim lRegex as LongPtr: lRegex = SOMEHOW_CALL_METHOD(lKlass, "options", 0, "error", AddressOf MyFunction)
End Sub
```

However we have no method of calling the method pointer we obtain? Unfortunately VBA doesn't supply a method to do so... On windows OS we use [`DispCallFunc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-dispcallfunc). See [example](https://github.com/sancarn/stdVBA/blob/master/src/WIP/STD_Automation_DLL.cls#L217-L218).

Is there an alternative to `DispCallFunc` defined in `libobjc`, `libc` or any other library we have access to natively on Mac?

Comment: You might be looking for [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/).

Comment: See also [C late binding with unknown arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885868).

Comment: @SteveSummit Thanks, thanks for both of these. Very interesting reads. I think resolving this will be a lot of experimentation with different approaches. ChatGPT suggested use of [`objc_msgSend`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1456712-objc_msgsend) too

Comment: SHooting at the moon, would this be of interest, https://github.com/thetrik/VBCDeclFix

Comment: @freeflow hah no, That's Windows 32-bit only :P The trik's work is legendary though.